# trouble importing scrapy python package in VSC

Tags: python, scrapy

I have Anaconda installed on my computer and I have installed the scrapy package via jupyter notebook and the anaconda terminal via pip install scrapy and conda install -c conda-forge scrapy. I can import scrapy in jupyter notebook. Now, I have went to the anaconda shell and put in the command like "scrapy startproject wikispider." I cd to that directory and then code . into VSC, where I could see the subdirectories for that directory (scrapy.cgf, items.py, middlewares.py, etc). I then went into the wikispider directory and created an article.py file. I cd to that file and tried to import scrapy. I keep getting the following message:"

```
       "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module name 'Scrapy"
```

Not sure why this is happening; Scrapy has been installed on via the terminal and I can use it in jupyter notebook. Also, I imported the pandas package to make sure I could do so and it worked. I am using an example out of a book.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All names in Python are case-sensitive.
Try `import scrapy`

Comment: Thank you for your response; I am aware of the cave-sensitivy and I have tried that already. It is just not working.

Comment: You're welcome. That was the first thing that came to my mind when I saw the Scrapy with first letter uppercase :)